# display email in different row in contact form

Tags: contact-us

in contact us page name and email are displaying in same row.

what changes i have to do to display email ,below name in demo site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the css from :

```
.form-list .field {
    float: left;
    width: 302px;
}
```

to

```
.form-list .field {
    width: 302px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to add a newer version of the contact form in your theme. The default template can be found at `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/contacts/form.phtml` and if you copy this across to your package and theme then you can make any change you need here.

Your file will end up being in the path `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/contacts/form.phtml`